# How to eliminate a shift/ reduce issue in Bison/Flex?

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, shift-reduce-conflict

I have a school project where I have to make a minipy compiler (kind of similar to python), and I have a shift/reduce conflict in my .synt file.  The problem is within this grammar:

```
INS:INS_AFF  
   |INS INS_AFF 
   |INS_IF
   |INS_FOR1
   |INS_FOR2
   |INS_WHILE
```

The problem only appeared after adding INS in the second line, but I need to add that in each line — otherwise, it won't work. So what other options do I have?

I tried every solution I ever found, but nothing worked. Either it won't work as it's supposed to, or it gives me more problems.

Comment: I'm not sure we have enough information to be able to help.  (I note in passing that normally upper-case names are reserved for tokens and lower-case names are used for non-terminals.  `INS` at least is a non-terminal.) It looks a bit as if you need rules along the lines of: `ins: ins_item | ins ins_item; ins_item: INS_AFF | INS_IF | INS_FOR1 | INS_FOR2 | INS_WHILE;`.  However, it is far from clear that this will fix your shift/reduce problem, but we'd need more grammar to be able to work that out.

Comment: Ideally, you'd create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  This would be a grammar file that contains a minimal subset of the `%token` lines and a minimal set of rules — no actions because those are almost certainly not a part of the problem.  And nothing after the second `%%` line.  It should reproduce the shift/reduce conflict you're getting.

Comment: Ok, voting to close because after two days, OP hasn't responded and the question cannot be answered in its present form.